# AngularJS: How to do Animated Scroll To Top with directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i am new in angular but still wrote a sample directive for Animated Scroll To Top effect. first see my code and jsfiddle in action https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/hzgjcojg/

### code

```
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="i in items" style="width: 100%; line-height: 30px;">
        {{i}} click me to scroll to me!
      </li>
    </ul>
    <scroll-on-click></scroll-on-click>
  </body>

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [];
  for (var i=0; i<100; i++) { $scope.items.push(i); }
});

app.directive('scrollOnClick', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    template:'<a title="Click here to go top" class="scrollup" href="#" style="display: inline;">Scroll</a>',
    link: function(scope, $elm) {
      $elm.on('click', function() {
        $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, "slow");
      });
    }
  }
});
```

visit this url https://webdesignerhut.com/animated-scroll-to-top-jquery/ just to see what kind of output i am trying to achieve with directive. in that web site when user scroll down then a arrow will come and when user click on that arrow then a smooth scrolling to upward happening.

### couple of issue in my above directive

1) in my code a arrow is coming but when clicking then smooth scrolling is not happening may be i have not include jquery dependency file. without jquery how can do the smooth scrolling with plain javascript ?

2) i want to show arrow image when user scroll down and very close to page end. how to achieve it in angular directive. basically i have to check user is close to page end from directive and if yes then i have to show arrow or append arrow in my directive div.

so please see my two points and help me to achieve my goal. thanks

Comment: please do not use jquery if possible when rectify my code. thanks

Comment: when i add jquery to my fiddle then it is working so new fiddle link is jsfiddle.net/tridip/hzgjcojg/2 but i want to achieve it without jquery dependency..........please help.

Comment: still got no suggestion or comment :(

Comment: no body say anything as if i asked super most complicated one.